# Flash CS6 How Do You Edit A Scene In Landscape Mode?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, landscape

I want my game to be played in landscape mode.

However, my app in CS6 is annoying to set down objects because when I'm adding stuff I see everything in Portrait mode, my quesiton is how can I change this so I'm editing/adding in landscape for Flash Professional CS6.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.  Create a new file, and have it set at the 800x480 landscape template, rather than the default.

There is probably a better way to do it, but this is the one I found.